# Math equation rendering problem

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, ios-app

[Is "The empty set is a subset of any set" a convention?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1953218)

**I have slow internet connection** and math expressions sometimes does not work.

[image: screenshot]

**This is how it should look like** ("page" reload helped)
[image: screenshot_correct]

**Text sample**:

$\varnothing\subset A$ means "for every object of $x$, if $x$ belongs to the empty set, then $x$ also belongs to the set A". This is a vacuous truth, because the antecedent($x$ belongs to the empty set) could never be true, so the conclusion always holds($x$ also belongs to the set A). So $\varnothing\subset A$ holds.

- App Version: 1.6.0.10
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.0.2 (Build 14A456)

Comment: Do you get the error on desktop as well?

Comment: Sounds legit to me: "Math processing error means for every object of math processing error, if math processing error belongs to the empty set, then math processing error also belongs to the set A." What exactly is the problem here?"

Comment: It looks strange for me. If it is ok, then I can close the issue.

Comment: It's not OK, I was joking. Usually if there's a problem with Mathjax, it shows a math processing error, and it's not uncommon to only occur in the mobile app, but not on desktop. Can you check if it happens on desktop too, since then we'd be able to say whether we reproduce the bug.

Comment: It works on desktop for me, so we need to confirm if this is something wrong with your device, or generally something with the mobile app, which would be something to report here and get fixed by the devs.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this happens just now and then. Further, this is not the fault of SE. I've seen this happening on more sites that have MathJax enabled. I am fairly sure that it is the fault of MathJax.

Reloading the page should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This is more or less by design.

I recently switched the app to use MathJax from the `cdn.mathjax.org` server rather than serve it up locally.  Largely because this is what math.se does and the app was woefully out of date.  Caching should keep this issue from cropping up regularly but if it's persistent I'll reconsider serving a local copy.